# Indesign: Is it possible to Replace frames those content a specific link with clipboard content?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I have a lot of frames (as icons) linked to one image (link). But now I want a glyph instead them. Is it possible to replace them with a glyph that I copied to clipboard? Any script?
Even is it possible to track down a specific link with its path within InDesign?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. If the existing frames have some object styles applied, you could use the Find/Change Object dialog and use "Contents of clipboard" as a replacing value. 
Otherwise, you could simply use the glyph as an external resource and relink the link to that file.
Alternatively, you may want to use a script to do the replacements.